# Restoring iphone 6s with broken home button

Tags: restore

I am trying to restore an iPhone 6s with a non functioning home button. iTunes tells me in order to restore it I need to click "trust this computer", however the iPhone says "iPhone is disabled, connect to itunes." , so there is no way to even unlock it to trust it. What should I do?

Comment: Which iOS are you using? Do you have AssistiveTouch enabled?

Comment: @jaydm26 ios 9. assistive touch is enabled, but siri and home dont do anything

Comment: Is there a computer that has a previous back up of the phone? If not, is the data important? I would suggest a DFU to reset the iPhone. If you choose to put the phone in DFU, remember to restore it to iOS 9, not iOS 10.

Comment: @jaydm26 and how would I put it into dfu with a broken home button? I have tried RecBoot and redsn0w to put it into recovery and dfu and neither worked

Answer (score 1):

Its iOS 10, right?
You may try going around: go to Camera, take a shot, then go to photos and tap on the left top button to see all photos. You should be prompted to enter password and after entering you're in. A message to trust computer should pop up.

Comment: its not ios 10. 9.something